# Get json value as string?

Tags: javascript, json

Say I have an object

```
var BOB = {
 "name": "bob",
 "height": 185
};
```

And I have another object which references a value from it

```
var PROPS = {
"bob": {
  "height": BOB.height
};
```

So now `PROPS.bob.height` will equal `185`. If I stringify the object, I get

```
{"bob": {"height": 185}}
```

Can I work out the string value of what was evaluated to return the value `185`. e.g. work out the source code from within the code ...:

```
var s = findOutTheSourceCode(PROPS);

// s would be
/*
{
"bob": {
  "height": BOB.height
}
*/
```

Comment: No, you can't !

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can iterate through all of the object properties to find the path. But it will work only in case values are unique

Comment: @k102 - but you'll never get `BOB.height` back, as that reference is gone, at best you'll get `185`, which is not what frumbert wants

Comment: @adeneo yes, but if you know in what objects to search, it still can be possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no. That information isn't stored anyway.

---

If the code was part of a function **and** you have a reference to that function **and** you are using a JS engine which supports this non-standard feature then you can call `thatfunction.toString()` and then try to find the relevant bit of code using (for example) pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **really bad** idea from the design point of view.

Anyway, answering to your question, the short answer is "NO, you can't".

But there is an **ugly** answer that says yes, at the cost of relying on using *eval* which is an even worst idea. Example:

```
var BOB = {
 "name": "bob",
 "height": 185
};

var PROPS_src = '{\n'
    + '  "bob": {\n'
    + '    "height": BOB.height\n'
    + '  }'
    + '}';

eval('var PROPS = '+PROPS_src);

console.log("PROPS_SRC:__________________");
console.log(PROPS_src);
console.log("PROPS:______________________");
console.log(PROPS);

// Output:
// PROPS_SRC:__________________
// {
//   "bob": {
//     "height": BOB.height
//   }}
// PROPS:______________________
// { bob: { height: 185 } }
```

But, as I said, all of that is a **really bad idea**. I hardly recommend you to redesign your data structures (and code if needed) in a way you can trace data origins aside.

For (fast and dirty) example:

```
var people = {
    bob: {
     "name": "bob",
     "height": 185
    }
};

var props = {
  "bob": {
    "someConstant": "Hello World",
    "_height": "height",
  }
};

function getProps(who){
    var out = {};
    Object.keys(props[who]).map(function(k){
        if (k.substring(0,1) == "_") {
            out[k.substring(1)] = people[who][props[who][k]];
        } else {
            out[k] = props[who][k];
        };
    }); 
    return out;
};

console.log("Raw:", props['bob']);
console.log("Calculated:", getProps('bob'));

// Output:
// Raw: { someConstant: 'Hello World', _height: 'height' }
// Calculated: { someConstant: 'Hello World', height: 185 }
```